# passing command line arguments to call batch job

Tags: java, spring-batch

I am very new to java and spring batch jobs. I have a sample piece of spring batch job and i want to know if i can run the code using command line arguments.

**strong text**

```
@Bean
public Job job(BtchJobCmtnNotfLstnr lstnr, JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory) throws DataAcesExcp
 {

        return jobBuilderFactory.get("Job").incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer()).listener(lstnr)
                .start(rdItmAndWrtInCsvk()).next(rdItmAndWrtInJsonk()).build();

}

@Bean
public Job job2(BtchJobCmtnNotfLstnr lstnr, JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory) throws DataAcesExcp {

        return jobBuilderFactory.get("Job1").incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer()).listener(lstnr)
                .start(rdItmAndWrtInCsvw()).next(rdItmAndWrtInJsonw()).build();
    }
```

so i have Job and Job1 and when i run this code it is working fine but both job, job 1 are getting executed.

expected result: i need to pass command line arguments that is if i pass job as arguments only job has to be executed the same way if i pass job1 as arguments only job1 has to be executed. Sorry i couldn't able to provide more info or code.

Comment: Do you use spring boot? If yes, you can specify in your command which job to launch using the `spring.batch.job.names` property

Comment: can you please elaborate. I am using spring boot and my batchjoblaunch.class has my job and job1. how can i call job1 using spring.batch.job.names. If possible please provide the code sample. Thanks!

Comment: Here is an example: the command `java -jar batch-apps.jar --spring.batch.job.names=job1` will run only `job1`.